# Aiohttp Unhandled exception, AssertionError when app receives high load

Tags: aiohttp

This is the exception I get when there is relatively higher load on the aiohttp based rest api. I'm unable to figure out the exact issue. Any leads would be appreciated.

aiohttp==3.8.5
uvloop==0.17.0
Using uvloop event loop policy with asyncio.
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())

Unhandled exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 512, in start
resp, reset = await task
File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 429, in _handle_request
assert self._request_handler is not None
AssertionError

I tried to reproduce the issue locally but I couldn't generate the same error but I managed to generate the error below after sending huge load which may not be related.

Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-21' coro=<RequestHandler.start() done, defined at .venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py:462> exception=AssertionError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 505, in start
request = self._request_factory(message, payload, self, writer, handler)
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_app.py", line 446, in _make_request
return _cls(
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_request.py", line 811, in **init**
super().**init**(*args, **kwargs)
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_request.py", line 188, in **init**
assert transport is not None
AssertionError